# Redirect to SignIn Activity after Log Out in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android Development, I want my user to be redirected when he signs out from application to sign in activity. For sign in, I am using Firebase Authentication

```
AuthUI.getInstance().
        signOut(getActivity()).
        addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        AuthenticationActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method invocation

```
AuthenticationActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
```

looks like it builds and returns an `Intent` that is unused. You probably intended the following:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Intent intent = AuthenticationActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Here's the [documentation for the `startActivity` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)).